# Specify namespace for an element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've got an XML for which I need to generate an XSD. My XML goes as follows:

**Instance:**

```
    <mes:GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS 
          xmlns:mes="http://abcd.com">
         <response>
            <messages>
               <item>
                  <date>15/04/2014 00:00:00</date>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <date>01/07/2014 10:01:32</date>
               </item>
            </messages>
         </response>
    </mes:GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS>
```

Please note that only the outermost element `GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS` belongs to a namespace `http://abcd.com` - the rest of the elements don't. How do I specify this in the XSD?

I've tried with following XSD but that gives me error:

**XSD:**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="response">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="messages">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="item" 
                          maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="date"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But when I tried to validate the instance with the XSD using an online validator, I ended up with this error:

> Not valid.
>      Error - Line 1, 95: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 95; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mes:GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS'.

Which is logical, as I did not provide the namespace in the XSD. Please help me understanding **how do I provide this namespace ONLY FOR THE OUTERMOST ELEMENT in my XSD.**

Answer (score 5):

You've got two things that aren't quite what you want.

- You want the GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS element to be in the namespace http://abcd.com.

  So add `targetNamespace="http://abcd.com"` to your schema element.
- You want the children of that element (which are all declared as local to the anonymous complex type of the GetInboundResponseGetInboundSMS element) to be unqualified.

  So change `elementFormDefault="qualified"` on the schema element to `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`.

The start-tag for your schema document should look something like this:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://abcd.com"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Include the schema element from default to qualified and it will work. If you want to use the same namespace in the XML document, Add that namespace in the prefix of the start and end tag of your XSLT. It works.